# Linux cannot boot with u-boot and FIT(flatten image tree)

Tags: linux, u-boot

This question is exactly identical with [Lostboy's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626471/linux-boot-arguments-with-u-boot-and-flat-image-tree-fit/44131020#44131020).
As I cannot find an answer from the post, ask again.

FIT includes a signed Kernel image(zImage) and FDT.
Target is Jetson-TK1, and it works pretty well with basic BSP.

Could you let me know what I check again?

Here I attach my ITS file and console log as follow:

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    description = "OS kernel image with one or more FDT blobs";
    #address-cells = <1>;

    images {
        kernel@1 {
                        description = "Kernel";
            data = /incbin/("./zImage");
            type = "kernel";
            arch = "arm";
            os = "linux";
            compression = "none";
            load = <0x81008000>;
            entry = <0x81008000>;
            kernel-version = <1>;
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
        fdt@1 {
            description = "Device Tree";
            data = /incbin/("./tegra124-jetson_tk1-pm375-000-c00-00.dtb");
            type = "flat_dt";
            arch = "arm";
            compression = "none";
            fdt-version = <1>;
            hash@1 {
                algo = "sha1";
            };
        };
    };
    configurations {
        default = "conf@1";
        conf@1 {
            description = "Linux Kernel, FDT blob.";
            kernel = "kernel@1";
            fdt = "fdt@1";
            signature@1 {
                algo = "sha1,rsa2048";
                key-name-hint = "dev";
                sign-images = "fdt", "kernel";
            };
        };
    };
};
```

and console returns,

```
Tegra124 (Jetson TK1) # ext2load mmc 0 0x90000000 /boot/zImage_rsa_signed.img
6099545 bytes read in 462 ms (12.6 MiB/s)
Tegra124 (Jetson TK1) # bootm 0x90000000
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 90000000 ...
   Using 'conf@1' configuration
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1,rsa2048:dev+ OK
   Trying 'kernel@1' kernel subimage
     Description:  Kernel
     Created:      2017-05-23   5:41:43 UTC
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x900000e4
     Data Size:    6037416 Bytes = 5.8 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x81008000
     Entry Point:  0x81008000
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   f88f771a166e767b449744e6a23a46c29cb544de
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 90000000 ...
   Using 'conf@1' configuration
   Trying 'fdt@1' fdt subimage
     Description:  Device Tree
     Created:      2017-05-23   5:41:43 UTC
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x905c2188
     Data Size:    59661 Bytes = 58.3 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
     Hash algo:    sha1
     Hash value:   2684084a852a74579900ab37d30fd7dc54bb5e27
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha1+ OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x905c2188
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8efee000, end 8efff90c ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Target hangs here.

Default extlinux.conf to boot has as follow;

```
TIMEOUT 30
DEFAULT primary

MENU TITLE Jetson-TK1 eMMC boot options

LABEL primary
      MENU LABEL primary kernel
      LINUX /boot/zImage_rsa_signed.img
      FDT /boot/tegra124-jetson_tk1-pm375-000-c00-00.dtb
      APPEND console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty1 no_console_suspend=1 lp0_vec=2064@0xf46ff000 mem=20
15M@2048M memtype=255 ddr_die=2048M@2048M section=256M pmuboard=0x0177:0x0000:0x02:0x43:0x00 tsec=32
M@3913M otf_key=c75e5bb91eb3bd947560357b64422f85 usbcore.old_scheme_first=1 core_edp_mv=1150 core_ed
p_ma=4000 tegraid=40.1.1.0.0 debug_uartport=lsport,3 power_supply=Adapter audio_codec=rt5640 modem_i
d=0 android.kerneltype=normal fbcon=map:1 commchip_id=0 usb_port_owner_info=0 lane_owner_info=6 emc_
max_dvfs=0 touch_id=0@0 board_info=0x0177:0x0000:0x02:0x43:0x00 net.ifnames=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw
 rootwait tegraboot=sdmmc gpt
```

modified....

```
Tegra124 (Jetson TK1) # printenv
arch=arm
baudrate=115200
board=jetson-tk1
board_name=jetson-tk1
boot_a_script=load ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}${script}; source ${scriptaddr}
boot_extlinux=sysboot ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} any ${scriptaddr} ${prefix}extlinux/extlinux.conf
boot_prefixes=/ /boot/
boot_scripts=boot.scr.uimg boot.scr
boot_targets=mmc1 mmc0 usb0 pxe dhcp
bootcmd=setenv usb_need_init; for target in ${boot_targets}; do run bootcmd_${target}; done
bootcmd_dhcp=run usb_init; if dhcp ${scriptaddr} boot.scr.uimg; then source ${scriptaddr}; fi
bootcmd_mmc0=setenv devnum 0; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_mmc1=setenv devnum 1; run mmc_boot
bootcmd_pxe=run usb_init; dhcp; if pxe get; then pxe boot; fi
bootcmd_usb0=setenv devnum 0; run usb_boot
bootdelay=2
bootpart=1
cpu=armv7
ethact=RTL8169#0
ethaddr=00:04:4b:25:b9:15
fdt_addr_r=0x82000000
fdt_high=ffffffff
initrd_high=ffffffff
kernel_addr_r=0x81000000
loadaddr=0x80408000
mmc_boot=if mmc dev ${devnum}; then setenv devtype mmc; run scan_dev_for_boot; fi
pxefile_addr_r=0x90100000
ramdisk_addr_r=0x82100000
scan_dev_for_boot=echo Scanning ${devtype} ${devnum}...; for prefix in ${boot_prefixes}; do run scan_dev_for_extlinux; run scan_dev_for_scripts; done
scan_dev_for_extlinux=if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${prefix}extlinux/extlinux.conf; then echo Found ${prefix}extlinux/extlinux.conf; run boot_extlinux; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi
scan_dev_for_scripts=for script in ${boot_scripts}; do if test -e ${devtype} ${devnum}:${bootpart} ${prefix}${script}; then echo Found U-Boot script ${prefix}${script}; run boot_a_script; echo SCRIPT FAILED: continuing...; fi; done
scriptaddr=0x90000000
soc=tegra124
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
usb_boot=run usb_init; if usb dev ${devnum}; then setenv devtype usb; run scan_dev_for_boot; fi
usb_init=if ${usb_need_init}; then setenv usb_need_init false; usb start 0; fi
vendor=nvidia

Environment size: 1997/8188 bytes
```

Comment: In my experience when the device hangs here "Starting kernel ...” the hand off from the boot loader to the kernel has problems.  A couple of quick observations:  `data = /incbin/("./zImage");` `compression = "none";` Is the zImage a compressed image? `Load Address: 0x81008000 Entry Point:  0x81008000` Can you verify with memory read that at that address is what you expect?  Verify against zImage header in a hex editor.

Comment: Please provide all of 'printenv' as well.  And note that yes, saying zImage is compression=none is correct in so far as that field indicates if U-Boot should be uncompressing the data or not, ie if booting a direct vmlinux or vmlinux.bz2/etc vs the kernel zImage loader.

Comment: Thanks 
@Tom Rini 
I edited main mesg to attach full 'printenv'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that nothing is setting bootargs.  If we look at the [documentation example](http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/uImage.FIT/howto.txt;h=2988a52aa176629483e9fe6333a1ec600cb93cc7;hb=HEAD#l113) we can see that first we still set bootargs, in that example by running some other command, then load the FIT and bootm it.  The APPEND line from your extlinux.conf file needs to be put into bootargs and then you should see Linux start up.

Comment: Thank you very much.
As your advice, 'bootargs' configuration cleared this issue.